# Best technique for topdown RPG-esque grid based scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

browser-based application, currently running on php/js/html5, jquery the only framework I'm using.

If I've got enough 64x64 images to fill up my screen about 100x, what technique would you recommend to move the images so that it looks like it's scrolling?

Think oldschool top-down RPG's if you will.

What I'm currently considering:

- HTML5 Canvas
- array1 with all the images, array keys being coords for each image
- array2 with just the images *currently on the screen*
- when moving to the left:

  - move all images 64px to the right (so that it moves in increments)
  - fetching the lacking images from the array1, stripping the ones that dropped off the screen
  - removing the images that dropped off the screen from the canvas

It's not an actual game, but that **is** the effect I'm trying to achieve.

I'll take any hints/tips I can get for this; from "use html tables instead of Canvas" to "impossible to streamline this for the web".

My main concern: speed. I'd like to be able to zoom out as well, to the point where I'd be using a LOT more images on the screen (32x32, perhaps even 16x16) but I'm aware that browser-based applications might not be up to that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the [MelonJS framework](http://www.melonjs.org/) to handle this for you. It can use maps from [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/), which is just plain awesome.

Comment: Looked at it, loved it, might use it. For now though, I'll not mark this as the correct answer, since I'd love to code some stuff myself ;) "We'll get back to you later"! Cheers!

Comment: Credit where due; no other responses ;) Cheers again, and I'll post here if I end up using it.

Comment: Great, I appreciate it, and I'm glad you like MelonJS!

Comment: Right, so. I ended up having a long hard look at MelonJS, and decided to code something myself. Both as an exercise and because I'd like to take a slightly different approach. As I said though, thanks a bunch for the linkage! :)